# Javascript destructure imported named class

Tags: javascript, oop

I want to use a class instance that was registered in a class.

I want to be able to use the named class direcley.

with the code I have now I can access the Dog and Cat classes methods the following way:

```
import animals from './Animals';
```

and than do:

```
const method = animals.cat.method();
```

destructure the object directly in the import didn't for me this time.

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
import { cat } from './Animals';

const method = cat.method();
```

This is the code I have:
Animals.js

```
import Cat from './Cat';
import Dog from './Dog';

class Animals {
    cat = new Cat();
    dog = new Dog();
}

const animals = new Animals();

export default animals;
```

I thought doing something like this:

```
   export { animals.cat as cat }
   export { animals.dog as dog }
```

But it didn't work.
What can I do to make it work?

Comment: Don't use a class for that, but plain object. Also you can't access `Animals.cat` because `.cat` is in the prototype, not the static class itself (you must read about Javascript prototypes). If you want to do that, create the cat and the dog as `static`.

Comment: The import syntax you’re using is _not destructuring._ That is a named import which requires a named export.

Comment: If you want to only import `cat` or `dog`, make them their own named exports, not properties of an object. You can't destructure an `import`, `import` syntax and destructuring are completely different things (with one marginal similarity).

Comment: To do separate named exports, you can do `export const cat = animals.cat;` and `export const dog = animals.dog;`